# What is the default isolation level in ef core 6 in BeginTransaction

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-6.0

I have following code

```
using (var transaction = dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
{
//my code creating a temp table and inserting rows into it
transaction.Commit();
}
catch                
{
transaction.Rollback();
throw;
}
```

I want to know what will be default isolation level
I'm trying to create a temp table in transaction and then performing some other queries and using that temp table in it.  I want to know what will happen when different users will call this at same time. I'm creating temp table inserting rows into it and then using it in my query my query is just a select query.

Comment: It is impossible to say this without knowing which DBMS is being used and what settings are set for it.

Comment: @alexanderpetrov microsoft sql server

Comment: Sql Server uses the `READ COMMITTED` isolation level by default. However, `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` can be enabled at the database level. Then it will be used by default. Moreover, the specified transaction isolation level remains when connection returning to the pool. Therefore, a connection taken from the pool elsewhere in the code can have any arbitrary value. For more information, see [Snapshot Isolation in SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/snapshot-isolation-in-sql-server)

Comment: If you need confidence, always explicitly set the transaction isolation level in each request: `.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted)`